# Please advise if upgrade EOSIO from current version to newer version. It's need Data Migration or not.

Tags: nodeos, keosd, private-blockchain

Now I already have EOSIO Private Blockchain for 4 VM Server (Ubuntu Server 18.04 TLS) for nodeos and 1 Wallet (Keosd) in Client (Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS) as diagram below

[image: EOSIO Setup 4 Nodes]
All Machine install EOSIO Software and CDT by compile from Source Code according to Official Document from 
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/autobuild-script

But I'm not sure if upgrade EOSIO in VM Server (All 4 Nodes) from current version to newer version in future. It's need Data Migration or not. Please advise me because I tried to search in web site and internet before but not found clearly answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say the current version you have installed on the VMs. So I will try a general answer.

Look up the [release notes](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases) and see if there are any specific instructions on upgrading.

Also, remember a blockchain is a distributed system. Even if you control all VMs in your private chain, you can still add a new VM to test the upgrade, install the new version on it, sync with the chain and if all is well, do the same for the other VMs. The key here is that you can do it gradually and the blockchain shouldn't have any down time during the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I will check release note again.

My current version is 1.5.2